# aurelia-cli generator cannot import dependencies

Tags: path, gulp, generator, require, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia-cli with typescript. There is a generator I made that requires a model file so it can iterate over its properties in order to generate the corresponding CRUD like this:

```
 let path = '../../src/modules/' + moduleName + '/models/' + modelFileName;
let mod = require(path);
let item = new mod[modelClassName]();

let keys = [];
for (var key in (item as any)){...}
```

Note that I have to require the model using a **relative** path here.
This works well in the most simple cases. The problem comes when the model file has additional imports that use an **absolute** path (relative to the root of the project) like this:

```
import { EnumNodeTypeXx } from 'resources/enums/enum-node-type-xx';
```

Where the *require()* call fails with the following error:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'resources/enums/enum-node-type-xx'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
...
```

If I make use of a path **relative** to the model itself in the model file, the generator doesn't complain:

```
import { EnumNodeTypeXx } from '../../../resources/enums/enum-node-type-xx';
```

The problem happens also if I reference a file coming from an NPM module with imports.

### Edit

After spending some time on aurelia-cli's code, I can see that it uses a (deprecated) nodejs feature where it overrides the processing of *ts* files by transpiling them before compiling them. After compilation, the problematic import is resolved with nodejs Module.require which can only require core modules, no_modules or relative path (according to the doc here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

So, as the generator uses node for module resolution and the compilation uses typescript compilation, I seem to be stuck. Does anyone see a way out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there doesn't seem to be an easy answer to this. I ended up overriding the require() method to handle my absolute paths differently as explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9259)
and pointed by zewa666 in [my github issue](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/710).

```
 const moduleProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(module)
  const origRequire = moduleProto.require
  moduleProto.require = function(request) {
    if (request.startsWith('resources') 
  || request.startsWith('services') 
  || request.startsWith('modules')) {//very naive approach but easy enough to understand
request = __dirname + '/../../src/' + request + '.ts';

  }
  return origRequire.call(this, request);
      }
```